# Use the same selectbox in multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I use jQuery, and I have multiple tabs, that look mostly different. There is a selectbox that's shared over all tabs and I basically want it to have the same values and selected value over all the different tabs, so if it's changed in one tab then it's also changed in the other tab.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1">
    Content 1
    <select>
        <option>op1</option>
        <option>op2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="tab-2">
    Content 2
    <select>
        <option>op1</option>
        <option>op2</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

And the tabs get selected by

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
}
```

I want the first selectbox to be copied on the second tab, or be equal to the other selectbox at all times. Is there a clean way to do this (not copying on tab.change() or something), or maybe a wholly different approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it works for you. The code is written in very hurry. sorry for inconvenience.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1">
Content 1
<span id="fcont"><select><option>op1</option><option>op2</option></select></span>
</div>
<div id="tab-2">
Content 2
<span id="scont"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

And in jQuery

```
$(function()
{
   var mysel= "";
   $("#tabs").tabs();              
    $('#tab-1').click(function()
   {
     mysel = $("#scont").html();
     if(mysel)
     {
       $("#fcont").html(mysel);
       $("#scont").html("");
     }
   });
   $('#tab-2').click(function()
   {
     mysel = $("#fcont").html();
     $("#scont").html(mysel);
     $("#fcont").html("");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems this is the best way to go, though I had something more elegant in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.clone` jQuery function.

```
$(SELECT).clone().append(NEWTAB_HTML);
```

In Detail.

```
$(function()
{
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $('#tab-2').click(function()
    {
        var newSelect = $('#tab-1 select').clone().attr('id','new_id_value');
        $(this).append(newSelect);
    });

});
```

Comment: .clone() adds a new element, I actually just want a view on the same element in another tab.

Comment: well so what does it make sense if you want to show same select there.?

Comment: you can wrap select box into a div and then move its html(select box) on requirement.

Comment: @aishazafar can you tell us how.?